# Change oracle smtp pl/sql email to courier font format

Tags: oracle, plsql, smtp

Im trying to send email from pl/sql.I have problem formatting the font.I want to change the email content to courier new.

```
message := myColumns||chr(10)||lpad('-',80,'-')||chr(13)||xmessage;
 v_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(v_Mail_Host, 25);
 utl_smtp.helo(v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);
 utl_smtp.mail(v_Mail_Conn, v_From);
 utl_smtp.rcpt(v_Mail_Conn, 'abc@hotmail.com');
 utl_smtp.data(v_Mail_Conn,
 --dbms_output.put_line(
  -- 'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||
   'From: '   || v_From || crlf ||
   'Subject: '|| v_Subject || crlf ||
   'To: '     || v_Recipient || crlf ||
   crlf ||
   xmessage|| crlf --||  -- Message body

 );
```

Please help .How i can convert the font of message body?

Comment: This code sends a plaintext message - there is no font except whatever font the recipient's mail system uses. To make formatted emails you need to send a multipart message with a text/html part.

Comment: For example, see: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql.php